# Auto apply .ng-invalid to other element

Tags: angular

I have this code

```
<div>
 <input formControlName="foo" />
</div>
```

In form validation, when `<input>` fails, Angular appends `.ng-invalid` css class to that element automatically, I would like to know if it can do same thing with other element (`<div>` in this case)?

Comment: you can add css class using ngClass

Comment: `<div [ngClass]="{ 'ng-invalid': formGroup.foo.invalid }">`

Comment: `<div [class.ng-invalid]="formGroup.foo.invalid">` is faster, @ExplosionPills

Comment: yes, but I still have to control it manually, what I would like to know is if Angular can help with that so I don't need to modify <div> tag or use other ng directives.